# Why must an automorphism of $Z_n$ be of the form $x \mapsto x^a$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

The proof that the automorphism group of $Z_n$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ in Dummit and Foote uses the fact that if $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(Z_n)$ then $\varphi(x) = x^a$ for some integer $a \in \mathbb Z$.

I can understand that this is the case because the isomorphism must send generators to generators. It seems (intuitively) that any other mapping of generators to generators won't preserve the group structure. But I don't feel comfortable with this rigorously yet; is there a proof for why any automorphism must be of the form $\varphi(x) = x^a$?

Comment: It is not clear whether you understand that "the isomorphism must send generators to generators", or not.

Comment: Your statement is false. Look for instance at the automorphism $x\mapsto-x$ of $\Bbb Z_3$. Can you please give the precise reference in Dummit and Foote for it?

Comment: If you want the multiplicative version $x^a$, then you should write ${\rm Aut}(C_n)$ with $\phi:C_n\rightarrow C_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,  since $\Bbb Z_n$ is cyclic, we can take $g$ to be a generator.    Then any homomorphism is determined by where you send $g$ (because it generates).  And any $y\in \Bbb Z_n$ is of the form $g^a$ for some $a$ (again because $g$ is a generator).

When the dust clears,  the rule will just be $x\to x^a.$

Comment: Since the operation on $\Bbb Z_n$ is $+$, we have $y=ag$, not $g^a$.

Comment: Well you're just switching notation.   @AnneBauval

Comment: @AnneBauval Note that the OP uses exponent notation though, so I think it's fine for the answer to as well.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OP shouldn't have used the notation $\mathbb{Z_n}$ then, because in this group the operation is clearly addition. There are other ways to denote multiplicative cyclic groups.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: and there you were, trying to be kind to a new user, but apparently that isn't the way to go on MSE these days.

Comment: @Mark: a subscript lower-case blackboard bold $n$ is barbaric and the OP didn't use one. The OP is a new user and it is quite clear what he or she meant. Aren't we supposed to be kind to new users, in particular.

Comment: @Mark You're right, that was a mistake and should be edited. Hopefully the question was clear either way, though.